# hold a lock until all goroutines finishes

Tags: go, distributed-system, consensus

Below is a piece of code written in Go taken from [Raft Locking Advice](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.824/labs/raft-locking.txt), rule 5:

```
  rf.mu.Lock()
  rf.currentTerm += 1
  rf.state = Candidate
  for <each peer> {
    go func() {
      rf.mu.Lock()
      args.Term = rf.currentTerm
      rf.mu.Unlock()
      Call("Raft.RequestVote", &args, ...)
      // handle the reply...
    } ()
  }
  rf.mu.Unlock()
```

Raft is some consensus algorithm and rf refers to Raft. What the above code is trying to do is that a leader is sending RPC requests to all its peers asking for a vote. As pointed out in the paragraph following the code, this code is not ideal because rf.currentTerm might has already been change before the subroutines are fired. The goal is for the states of rf to stay unchanged while its peers are voting for it.

My remedy would be to use the wait group to let the code wait before the last `rf.mu.Unlock`. That will certainly solves the problem mentioned. However rule 4 in the advice states: `it's usually a bad idea to hold a lock while doing anything that might wait`.

The solution the article proposed is the following:

> One way to fix this is for the created goroutine to
> use a copy of rf.currentTerm made while the outer code holds the lock.

but I am not quite sure about what it means.

Comment: In this case I don't see any code that would wait. Your top goroutine locks and launches several other goroutines and then unlocks. Nothing it does waits.

Although Go code like this using explicit mutexes is kind of bad in my opinion. I would try to write it using channels passing immutable values around. For example you could have a "goroutine server" that pumps out incrementing Term values onto a channel. But whatever works.

Comment: What I mean is that if I add all the subroutines into a wait group and let the code wait before ```rf.mu.Unlock```, then I will indeed have to wait. And I need to do this because I need ```rf.currentTerm``` and ```rf.state``` to be consistent through all goroutines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass argument to a go routine function, for example:

```golang
  rf.mu.Lock()
  rf.currentTerm += 1
  rf.state = Candidate
  for <each peer> {
    go func(ct CurrentTerm) {
      rf.mu.Lock()
      args.Term = ct
      rf.mu.Unlock()
      Call("Raft.RequestVote", &args, ...)
      // handle the reply...
    } (rt.currentTerm)
  }
  rf.mu.Unlock()
```

I'm not sure this is the best solution without understanding what you're trying to accomplish.